# How to manually enterText box values while running Selenium WebDriver using NUnit in c#

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am new to selenuim, I am trying to implement Selenium WebDriver with NUnit in c#. For this I created a test project in visual studio.

I am uisng below code to access username and password.

```
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("ABC");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("XXXX");
```

Now How to manually enterText box values while running Selenium WebDriver using NUnit in C#

Thanks

Comment: In your Automated test script, you have entered values for UserName and Password by using SendKeys. Values will be typed/entered automatically in corresponding text box. Why does it need to enter manually?

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys is used for passing values to any text box in Selenium WebDriver. As you are sending password by SendKeys, similarly find any text box through identifiers and use SendKeys(). I hope this helps.